# MATLAB CLASSES getter and setters

Tags: matlab, oop, matlab-class

I come from a Java background. I am having issues with classes in Matlab particularly getters and setters. getting a message saying conflict between handle and value class I'm a little lost with what to do so any help for lack of a better word will be helpful.

```
classdef Person
properties(Access = private)
    name;
    age; 
end


methods
    % class constructor
    function obj = Person(age,name)         
             obj.age = age;
             obj.name = name;
    end

    %getters
    function name = get.name(obj)          
    end

    function age = get.age(obj)
    end

    %setters
    function value = set.name(obj,name)
    end

    function value = set.age(obj,age)
    end

end
```

end

Answer (score 9):

### Implementation

Since your class is currently a subclass of the default Value class, your setters need to return the modified object:

```
function obj = set.name(obj,name)
end
function obj = set.age(obj,age)
end
```

From [the documention](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html#brfylwk-3): "If you pass [a value class] to a function, the function must return the modified object."  And [in particular](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html#brqera6): "In value classes, methods ... that modify the object must return a modified object to copy over the existing object variable".

Handle classes (`classdef Person < handle`) do not need to return the modified object (like returning `void`):

```
function [] = set.name(obj,name)
end
function [] = set.age(obj,age)
end
```

### Value vs. Handle

Going a bit deeper, the difference between a Value class and a Handle class lies mostly in assignment:

- Assigning a Value class instance to a variable creates a copy of that class.
- Assigning a Handle class instance to a variable create a reference (alias) to that instance.

The Mathworks has a [good rundown](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html#brfylwk-3) on this topic.
To paraphrase their illustration, the behavior of a Value class is

```
% p  is an instance of Polynomial
p = Polynomial(); 
% p2 is also an instance of Polynomial with p's state at assignment
p2 = p;
```

and of a Handle class is

```
% db is an instance of Database
db = Database();
% db2 is a reference to the db instance
db2 = db;
```

Comment: When using a handle class, no need to write `[] = set.name(obj,name)`. Just `set.name(obj,name)` will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Quick'n Dirty from the Java perspective:
- "handle" classes are what your mind is set to. proper object instances with pointers to them. use them.
- "value" classes are always returning a full clone of whatever object (which has been modified by what you just did, e.g. setting a name).

the reason they have both in Matlab is that in Matlab you would expect the "value" behaviour natively. Imagine you have a matrix `A = [1 2; 3 4]`, then assign that via `B = A`. if you now set `B(1) = -1` you'd hope that `A(1)` is still 1, right? this is because matlab keeps track of "copies" and truly creates them as you modify different variables initially set to the same matrix. in OOP you'd have `A(1)=-1` now as everythings an object reference.

furthermore, "native" matlab routines dont have a "this/self/me" variable that contains the instance reference to access from within functions. instead, the convention is that the class instance will be prepended to the function's argument list.
so for a function call `myclass.mymethod(arg1,arg1)`, the declaration must be

```
function mymethod(this, arg1, arg2)
  % Note that the name you choose for "this" is arbitrary!
end
```

mind you, this is the java-perspective (and also my favourite one), the above function call is equivalent to `mymethod(myclass,arg1,arg1)`. this is more native to matlab-style, but somehow makes it harder to see you're calling an objects method.

now, regarding setters/getters: for **handle** classes, everything feels java-ish now:

```
classdef MyClass < handle

properties
   MyProp;
end

methods
   function set.MyProp(this, value)  %Note: setMyProp is also valid!
       ... % do checks etc, trigger calls, 
       this.MyProp = value; 
   end

   function value = get.MyProp(this)
       ... % notify, update, triggers etc
       value = this.MyProp; 
   end 
end
```

Of course it goes without saying that you dont need to define a getter if you just want to return the value, i.e. `myclassinstance.MyProp` will work without any just as well.

Finally, getters/setters for value classes are something that [never encountered me/i never needed] in my 7 years of matlab oop, so my advise would be to go with handle classes and enjoy happy matlab coding :-)
otherwise, the above explanation & official matlab docs is doing the job for value class getter/setters.