# Cell Array of Player Objects Not Printing All Fields

Tags: matlab

I've written a basic class definition as follows:

```
classdef player

    properties
        team
        name
        rating
        ranking
    end

    methods
    end

end
```

I get a cell array of player objects, called `allPlayers`, with every field but ranking already set. I then call the below function on it:

```
function setRankings(players)
    for i = 1 : length(players)
        players{i}.ranking = i;
    end
end
```

At this point, all the fields of each player object should be set.  I call the below function to display each field:

```
function displayPlayers(players)
    for i = 1 : length(players)
       current = players{i};
       disp(['Name: ', current.name]);
       disp(['Team: ', current.team]);
       disp(['Rating: ', current.rating]);
       disp(['Ranking: ', current.ranking]);
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, each player prints out as follows (just an example):

```
'Name: '    'Shleifer,Sam'

Team: Yale
    'Rating: '    '5.050000'

Ranking:
```

So it looks like the ranking field doesn't actually get set by `setRankings`.

Why is this?

Comment: The rankings are not being set because `player` is a value class, as opposed to handle, and you're not returning the modified object from the function.  A brief explanation of the difference is [available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077642/matlab-classes-getter-and-setters/27079193#27079193).

Comment: I am honored to be a part of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behavior you desire you must make your class a 'handle' class - as opposed to a 'value' class. See this [link](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) for more information.

This is how to do it:

```
classdef player < handle

    properties
        team
        name
        rating
        ranking
    end

    methods
    end

end
```

Note that you can use value class too, but in that case you'd have to return the new list of players in `setRanking`.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Any idea why the rankings would be getting set to characters instead of integers?  I indicate i ranges from 1 to length(players) so I'm a little lost.  Thanks again!

Comment: `disp(['Ranking: ', num2str(current.ranking)]`