# MATLAB class method/property with same name

Tags: matlab, class

Is it possible to have classInstance.A() method set the property of classInstance.A ?

I get an error when i try to define a function A with the same name as the property A.

Due to this i usually do something like classInstance.setA() to set the property classinstance.A. But i think the code would look cleaner if the method to set the property could simply have the same name as the field.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077642/matlab-classes-getter-and-setters

Comment: Do you only set `A` or when you "get" `A` do you expect the property rather than calling the method?

Comment: When I "get" A I expect the property rather than method yes. To "set" A I would use .A()